# passing multiple parameters to getJSON creating issues

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am using Ajax-Json script. But very new to these languages. I am trying [shopping cart example](http://www.sanwebe.com/2015/03/ajax-shopping-cart-with-php-and-jquery). But remove item from cart is not working. I have function like below in

**js**

```
//Remove items from cart
    $("#shopping-cart-results").on('click', 'a.remove-item', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 

        var pcode = $(this).attr("data-code"); //get product code
        var pcolorname = $(this).attr("data-color"); //get product color
        alert(pcode);
        alert(pcolorname);
        $(this).parent().fadeOut(); //remove item element from box
        $.getJSON( "cart_process.php", {"remove_code":pcode, "remove_color":pcolorname} , function(data){ //get Item count from Server
             alert(data);
            $("#cart-info").html(data.items); //update Item count in cart-info
            $(".cart-box").trigger( "click" ); //trigger click on cart-box to update the items list
        });
    });
```

In above code, `pcode, pcolorname` are showing proper values and `alert(data);` is showing like `[object, Object]` which I don't know is coming right or wrong.

I have a product which is having multiple colors. e.g Product1, blue ; Product1, red. When I added both in shopping cart and clicked on Product1, blue to remove then cart becomes empty which should not happen.

`cart_process.php` is having functions to show shopping cart, remove item from cart. In that functions I have passed the product code and product color name. still its not working properly.

**cart_process.php** Code

```
################## list products in cart ###################
if(isset($_POST["load_cart"]) && $_POST["load_cart"]==1)
{
    if(isset($_SESSION["products"]) && count($_SESSION["products"])>0){ //if we have session variable
        $cart_box = '<ul class="cart-products-loaded">';
        $total = 0;
        foreach($_SESSION["products"] as $product){ //loop though items and prepare html content
            $cart_box .=  '<li>' . $product["name"].', '.$product["colorname"] .' (Qty : ' . $product["qty"]. ') &mdash; ' . $currency. sprintf("%01.2f", ($product["price"] * $product["qty"])). ' <a href="#" class="remove-item" data-code="'.$product["code"].'" data-color="'.$product["colorname"].'">&times;</a></li>';
            $subtotal = ($product["price"] * $product["qty"]);
            $total = ($total + $subtotal);
        }
        $cart_box .= "</ul>";
        $cart_box .= '<div class="cart-products-total">Total : '.$currency.sprintf("%01.2f",$total).' <u><a href="view_cart.php" title="Review Cart and Check-Out">Check-out</a></u></div>';
        die($cart_box); //exit and output content
    }else{
        die("Your Cart is empty"); //we have empty cart
    }
}

################# remove item from shopping cart ################
if(isset($_GET["remove_code"]) && isset($_GET["remove_color"]) && isset($_SESSION["products"]))
{
    $product_code   = filter_var($_GET["remove_code"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //get the product code to remove
    $prod_color   = filter_var($_GET["remove_color"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //get the product color to remove
    $product = array();
    foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) //loop through session array var
    {
        if($cart_itm["code"]!= $product_code && $cart_itm["colorname"]!= $prod_color){ //item does,t exist in the list
            $product[] = array('colorname'=>$cart_itm["colorname"], 'name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'code'=>$cart_itm["code"], 'qty'=>$cart_itm["qty"], 'price'=>$cart_itm["price"]);
        }
        $_SESSION["products"] = $product;
    }

    $total_items = count($_SESSION["products"]);
    die(json_encode(array('items'=>$total_items)));
}
```

Values by `getJSON` are not passing to `remove item from shopping cart` in cart_process.php (in above code). If I `echo $_GET["remove_code"]` and `$_GET["remove_color"]` nothing gets displayed. I guess call is not going properly so whatever i `echo` in that `if loop` nothing gets displayed.

I am not able to understand where I am making mistake. Can anyone please help me in this?

Comment: do a `console.log(data);` instead of `alert(data);` and check what data object contains on console.

Comment: I agree with Sudhansu, logging the variable to console could help you by properly accessing the value.

Comment: @Sudhansu Choudhary : `Object { items: 0 }` this is what I am getting. What does that means?

Comment: So try console.log(pcode.items) it looks like the object has such property.

Comment: @pbwned : By `console.log(pcode.items) ` its showing `undefined`.

Comment: @Sudhansu Choudhary : does that mean, values of `pcode, pcolorname` are not passing correctly to `getJSON` method?

Comment: try logging data.items like `console.log(data.items);` if you are not getting anything or u get `undefined` then "cart_process.php" is not returning the desired response, debug it.. however provided `pcode` and `pcolorname` that yor are passing are valid.

Comment: @pbwned : by `console.log(pcode); console.log(pcolorname);` its showing proper values of item to be removed.

Comment: and to answer if values of `pcode` and `pcolorname` are not passing correctly, the syntax is fine, perhaps you can echo those value in `.php` file. Also log data.items as I've mentioned in my previous comment

Comment: @Sudhansu Choudhary : `console.log(data.items);` giving `0`. :( and  by echo values in  `cart_process.php` is not displaying values on screen or in console. I have added the code from `cart_process.php`. Not able to find out the cause by debug.

Answer (score 0):

if you use j Query 1.6 or above  then use

```
var pcode = $(this).prop("data-code"); //get product code
var pcolorname = $(this).prop("data-color"); //get product color
```

i hope these will help you

Comment: @ Anurag Deokar : I am having `jquery-1.11.2.min.js`. with above lines its showing `undefined` on alert `pcode, pcolorname`.

Comment: "data-code" and "data-color" these attributes is present in  $("#shopping-cart-results")  if these is presen

Comment: $(function () {
        $("#shopping-cart-results").on('click', function (e) {
            var pcode = $(this).attr("data-code"); //get product code
            var pcolorname = $(this).attr("data-color"); //get product color
            alert(pcode + ' ' + pcolorname);
        });
    });  <input id="shopping-cart-results" type="button" value="button" data-code="12345" data-color="Black" />  these work fine

Comment: @ Anurag Deokar : yes, in my above code also my  `alert(pcode);alert(pcolorname);` shows correct values but passing that values by `getJSON` and accessing them in `cart_process.php` are going wrong somewhere. I am not able to figure it out.